# Proper error logging for node applications

Tags: node.js, logging

I am developing an express project which will have multiple modules/services in it. The folder structure looks mostly like this:

```
-- app.js
 -- payment_service
    -- routes.js
    -- index.js
    -- models
      -- model_1.js
      -- model_2.js
```

APIs in `index.js` are the only exposed APIs and they work as a gateway for all requests coming for this module/service.

Most of the services can throw operational error under many circumstances, so manual intervention may needed to fix things. So I need to:

1. Log errors properly with proper context so that some person/script can do the needful.
2. Figure out the reason of failure.

There will be dedicated teams owning each service. So I should be able to differentiate between error logs for each service so that it can be aggregated and forwarded to concerned person.

I decided to go with ELK stash so that I can generate reports by script.

The main problem that I am facing is that I can't maintain correlation between logs. For example; If a request comes and it travels through five functions and each function logs something then I can't relate those logs.

One way is to create a child logger for each request and pass it to all the functions but that seems to be extra overhead passing logger instance to all the functions.

Another option is to use something like [verror](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verror) and do the logging only at entry point of the service/module so that the whole context can be contained in the log. This approach looks ok for logging errors, however it can't help with info and debug logs - they help me a lot in development and testing phase.

For the sake of differentiating between error logs, I am going to create

1. A dedicated logger for each service with log level error.
2. An application wide generic logger for info and debug purpose.

Is this the correct approach?

What will be the best way so that I can achieve all the requirements in simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use a logger and you don't need anything too complex. For example:

`npm install 12factor-log`

Then create a file in your root folder near app.js (or in a `/lib` folder is where I'd place libraries)

*logger.js*

```
const Log = require('12factor-log');

module.exports = (params) => {
  return new Log(params);
}
```

Then in your modules, import your logger and pass in the module name when you instantiate it so you can track where statements come from...

*model_1.js*

```
var log = require('./logger')({name: 'model_1'});

// ... 

log.info("Something happened here");

// ...

try {
  // ...
catch (error) {
  const message = `Error doing x, y, z with value ${val}`;
  log.error(message);
  throw new Error(message);
}
```

Then handle error gracefully at your controller -> view layer for user-friendly experience.

Your logs would print something like this:

```
{"ts":"2018-04-27T16:37:24.914Z","msg":"Something happened here","name":"model_1","type":"info","level":3,"hostname":"localhost","pid":18}
```

---

As far as correlation of logs, if you see in the output above it includes the hostname of the machine it's running on, and also the name of the module and severity level. You can import this JSON into Logstash and load into Elasticsearch and it will store JSON for easy search and indexing.

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

Comment: Hi, when I talk about correlation, I mean correlation within a request, like if a user request travels through three functions, I should be able to correlate all three logs.

Comment: You can solve that with you authorization header and time stamps. Assuming each request is validated with an auth token (i.e. JWT), you can generate a unique request ID and pass the “request” object along with each subsequent call. Simply add “[request.id] My log statement” ... in each one and you can easily search for that string in Elasticsearch. (Sorry writing this on my phone)

Comment: You don’t need to build a custom logger, but you can build a helper function to concat IDs and messages into the log message. Example logMessage(req, message) and it will concat string and request ID and return your message or pass in logger and let it handle it all like a wrapper function.

Comment: but for that I need to pass req object everywhere, that I don't want to do.It will be an overhead and I need to mock it in contexts where my services are not serving http requests.

Answer (score 0):

Logging is complex and many people have worked on it. I would suggest not doing so yourself.

So, not following my own advice, I created my own logging package:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/woveon-logger

`npm install woveon-logger`

This prints file and line numbers of errors and messages, has logging levels and aspect-oriented logging, and can dump a stack trace in one call. It even has color coding options. If you get stuck and need some feature in logging, let me know.

```
let logger1 = new Logger('log1', {level : 'info', debug : true, showname : true};
let logger2 = new Logger('log2', {level : 'verbose', debug : true, showname : true};
...
log1.info('Here is a log message, that is on line 23.');
log1.verbose('Does not show');
log2.verbose('Shows because log2 is verbose logging');
log2.setAspect('IO', true);
log2.aspect('IO', 'Showing aspect IO logging, for logs for IO related operations');
```

> [2018-06-10T10:43:20.692Z] [INFO--] [log1  ] [path/to/myfile:23] Here is a log message, that is on line 23.
>
> [2018-06-10T10:43:20.792Z] [VERBOS] [log2  ] [path/to/myfile:25] Shows because log2 is verbose logging
>
> [2018-06-10T10:43:20.892Z] [IO----] [log2  ] [path/to/myfile:27] Showing aspect IO logging, for logs for IO related operations

Also, some other features like:

```
log1.throwError('Logs this as both a line of logging, and throws the error with the same message');
log1.printStack('Prints this label next to the stack trace.');
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use grackle_tracking library https://www.getgrackle.com/analytics_and_tracking

It logs errors & traffic to your db.